# get specific class from a nest of <ul><li>

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/5MSAb/1/

It has a nested `<ul><li>` made for jstree.

I need the the id of the li where '.jstree-checked' class in inserted.

In the jsfiddle I am just printing all the ids on the console and not searching for a specific class.

I am not able to get all the ids.

Comment: If I'm not missing anything, are you just looking for: `$('li.jstree-checked')`

Comment: Yes but all of those in the ul li nest.

Comment: You *cannot* have duplicate ids. Your HTML is broken. Go fix that.

Comment: The nesting doesn't pose a problem for a jQuery selector.  `$('li.jstree-checked')` will get all matching elements, regardless of their position in the tree.  I think you need to update the question to be a little clearer, and also update the HTML to never have the same id twice.

Comment: @Milimetric It will just return the first matched element. I need all of them. I have updated the HTML.

Comment: @turtle55, a jQuery selector returns an array: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/.  In this case, you can see what I mean by using `$('li.jstree-checked').each(function(){ /* do something and put a breakpoint here */ });` and seeing that the inner function gets called once for every element that matches the selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('li').filter('.jstree-checked').something();
```

would search all the li with .jstree-checked.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('li.jstree-checked').each(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

It will give you what you want.
I checked your mark up, by the way, it is highly unrecommended that using same ID for different objects.

Comment: not exactly ... this will only give you the id attribute of the _first_ matched element.

But: Thumbs up for the markup check!

Comment: I cant have same id. Thats my product id which I need based on what products are checked. And yes it gives me only first matched element

Comment: It's not just "highly unrecommended", it's actually not at all valid to have duplicate ids.

Comment: @KevinBallard Yes yes true.. I didnt realize what Sang wrote uptil now. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery wildcard operator '*' to accomplish this:

```
$('[class*=jstree-checked]').click(function(){
    alert(this.id);  
});
```

Comment: Possible ... but significantly slower than `$('li.jstree-checked')` (60% slower on FF 9.0.1 Win7) ... see http://jsperf.com/class-selector-against-class